# dhcp static assignment doesn't clean bind after DHCPRELEASE

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, bind, ddns

I've got a set of virtual machines inside VirtualBox on a OSX host.

My Gateway-VM is Ubuntu 13.04 with 4 NICs. On this machine ISC-DHCP-Server and Bind9 are running and DDNS-updates work fine when the supplied IP is coming out of the defined address-pool for the respective NIC.

If I do assign a static address for a client-machine, then the entry is created in bind, but when I poweroff that VM and the DHCPRELEASE is issued, the DNS-entries aren't deleted.

Contents of /var/log/syslog when VM is booting:

```
Aug 11 21:04:55 raring-gw dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 08:00:27:1f:20:81 via eth2
Aug 11 21:04:55 raring-gw dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.102.35 to 08:00:27:1f:20:81 via eth2
Aug 11 21:04:55 raring-gw dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.102.35 (192.168.102.1) from 08:00:27:1f:20:81 via eth2
Aug 11 21:04:55 raring-gw dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.102.35 to 08:00:27:1f:20:81 via eth2
Aug 11 21:04:55 raring-gw named[1242]: client 192.168.103.1#46752/key rndc-key: updating zone 'adnet/IN': update unsuccessful: precmysql.services.adnet: 'name not in use' prerequisite not satisfied (YXDOMAIN)
Aug 11 21:04:55 raring-gw named[1242]: client 192.168.103.1#46752/key rndc-key: signer "rndc-key" approved
Aug 11 21:04:55 raring-gw named[1242]: client 192.168.103.1#46752/key rndc-key: updating zone 'adnet/IN': deleting rrset at 'precmysql.services.adnet' A
Aug 11 21:04:55 raring-gw named[1242]: client 192.168.103.1#46752/key rndc-key: updating zone 'adnet/IN': adding an RR at 'precmysql.services.adnet' A
Aug 11 21:04:55 raring-gw dhcpd: Added new forward map from precmysql.services.adnet. to 192.168.102.35
Aug 11 21:04:55 raring-gw named[1242]: client 192.168.103.1#46752/key rndc-key: signer "rndc-key" approved
Aug 11 21:04:55 raring-gw named[1242]: client 192.168.103.1#46752/key rndc-key: updating zone '168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN': deleting rrset at '35.102.168.192.in-addr.arpa' PTR
Aug 11 21:04:55 raring-gw named[1242]: client 192.168.103.1#46752/key rndc-key: updating zone '168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN': adding an RR at '35.102.168.192.in-addr.arpa' PTR
Aug 11 21:04:55 raring-gw dhcpd: Added reverse map from 35.102.168.192.in-addr.arpa. to precmysql.services.adnet.
```

This is in the logentry, when the VM is shut down:

```
Aug 11 21:08:18 raring-gw dhcpd: DHCPRELEASE of 192.168.102.35 from 08:00:27:1f:20:81 via eth2 (not found)
```

The forward-zone-file contains this entry for the VM:

```
precmysql       A   192.168.102.35
                TXT "000d0dbca2b85df43a3464744da73ab515"
```

The reverse-zone-file contains:

```
35          PTR precmysql.services.adnet.
```

In /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf the host is defined as follows:

```
host precmysql {
    hardware ethernet 08:00:27:1F:20:81;
    fixed-address 192.168.102.35;
    option host-name "precmysql";
    ddns-hostname "precmysql";
}
```

This is the DDNS-configuration of the DHCP-server:

```
ddns-update-style interim;
ddns-updates on;
ignore client-updates;
update-static-leases on;
```

I looked into the /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases and none of the static-declarations are recorded there. It contains only entries for the assignments coming out of the defined address-pool.

Has anyone come across the same issue and maybe has a solution? Thanks!

Comment: do you have document to setup dns and dhcp. Please provide the documents